# I keep getting the error name 'Blog_Post' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am makeing a blog and the blog has a delete button. hen ever you click the button you are, spouse, to get taken back to the home page but you get this error name 'Blog_Post' is not defined. Ant help would be appreciated.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class create_blog_post(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/creat_post.html'
    fields = ('post_title', 'blog_content')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_app:all')

class view_blog_post(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/view_post.html'

def delet_blog_post(request, id):
    blog_post = Blog_Post.objects.get(id=blog_post_id)
    blog_post.delete()
    return redirect("/")

class all_blog_posts(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/all_posts.html'
    #slug_url_kwarg = "slug"
```

Comment: It is better to use `BlogPost` instead of `Blog_Post`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line, you don't declare blog_post_id anywhere
Blog_Post.objects.get(id=blog_post_id)

You need
blog_post_id = id. Or just id=id    Where id is what you sent to the delete_blog_post function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from .models import Blog_Post

User = get_user_model()


class create_blog_post(generic.CreateView):
    model = Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/creat_post.html'
    fields = ('post_title', 'blog_content')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_app:all')


class view_blog_post(generic.DetailView):
    model = Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/view_post.html'


def delet_blog_post(request, id):
    blog_post = Blog_Post.objects.get(id=blog_post_id)
    blog_post.delete()
    return redirect("/")


class all_blog_posts(generic.ListView):
    model = Blog_Post
    template_name = 'blog_app/all_posts.html'
    #slug_url_kwarg = "slug"
```

Comment: I had to change id=blog_post_id to id=id like the second response siad.